# Github in App login and Authentication in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, oauth-2.0, github-api

I want to create github login and Authentication inside the flutter app without redirecting to web browser. Everything should be inside the app. Is there a way to do it

Comment: flutter web? android or ios?, You can't override the default method of handling authentication. So accept what its offers.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no secure way to do that.

#### References

- [Embedded User Agents in Native Apps | OAuth 2.1 specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-1-03#page-67)
- [Use a System Browser | oauth.com](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/oauth-native-apps/use-system-browser)
- [Google Blocks OAuth Requests Made Via Embedded Browsers | auth0.com](https://auth0.com/blog/google-blocks-oauth-requests-from-embedded-browsers)